# When I try to publish a post to a predefined date it doesn't work in my django app

Tags: python, django, datetime

When I try to publish a post to a later date It doesn't work. It simply publishes the post with the later date. for instance if I create a post on 4/9/2017 which is today but I select 4/28/2017 as the publish date, it will simply publish the post today with todays date on it. When I select a future date I want it published on that date. I'm not a django pro and until recently never had to post in the future just the day of. In addition to posting on a particular day in the future. I would also like to select the time the post is posted. Here is my code

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils.text import slugify

from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Greeting(models.Model):
    when = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)


class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,
            self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')


# relative to media_cdn i.e. media_cdn/20/car.jpg
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "{}/{}".format(instance.id, filename)


class Post(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
       ('draft', 'Draft'),
       ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
                              null=True,
                              blank=True,
                              height_field='height_field',
                              width_field='width_field')
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=500,
                                 null=True,
                                 blank=True,
                                 )
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                       null=True,
                                       blank=True,
                                       )
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                      null=True,
                                      blank=True,
                                      )
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               related_name='blog_posts',
                               null=True,
                               blank=True,)
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='draft')
    video = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    video_path = models.CharField(max_length=320,
                                  null=True,
                                  blank=True,)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=320,
                           null=True,
                           blank=True, )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=320,
                            null=True,
                            blank=True, )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager.
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)



def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)


pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, sender=Post)


class Feed(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    # newest first

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-id"]



    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
                              null=True,
                              blank=True,
                              height_field='height_field',
                              width_field='width_field')

    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                       null=True,
                                       blank=True,
                                       )
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                      null=True,
                                      blank=True,
                                      )
```

heres my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post, Feed, Image
from pagedown.widgets import PagedownWidget
import datetime


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    body = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget)
    publish = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.SelectDateWidget,
        initial=datetime.date.today,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title",
            "body",
            "author",
            # "image",
            "image_url",
            "video_path",
            "video",
            "publish",
            "tags",
            "status",
            "name",
            "url"
        ]

        labels = {
            "video": "Embed",
            "url": "Site URL",
            "name": "Post Source"

        }
```

EDIT
my views.py

```
  import datetime
  import feedparser
  import os
  import random
  from django.conf import settings
  from django.contrib import messages
  from django.core.mail import send_mail
  from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
  from django.db.models import Count, Q
  from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404, redirect
  from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
  from taggit.models import Tag
  from .forms import ContactForm, SubmitForm, FeedForm
  from .forms import PostForm, ImageForm
  from .models import Post, Article, Feed
  from .my_scraps import scrape_world
  from .tasks import the_star, behind, pan_task


  def index(request):
      if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
          return redirect('/')

      articles = Article.objects.all()[:12]
      title = 'in other news'

      # get_vlad = get_vlad_tv()
      world = scrape_world()[:6]

      mergence = world #+ get_vlad

      random.shuffle(mergence)


      context = {
          "worlds": mergence,
          # "articles": articles,
          "title": title,
          # "vlad": get_vlad,
          # "darko": darko,
      }
      return render(request, 'index.html', context)




  def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
      if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
          object_list = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')
      else:
          object_list = Post.published.all().order_by('-id')
      articles = Article.objects.all()[:8]
      # latest_article = Post.published.latest('created')

      query = request.GET.get("q")
      if query:
          object_list = object_list.filter(
              Q(title__icontains=query) |
              Q(body__icontains=query) |
              Q(tags__name__in=[query])
          ).distinct()

      tag = None
      if tag_slug:
          tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
          object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])
      paginator = Paginator(object_list, 15) # 3 posts in each page
      page = request.GET.get('page')
      try:
          posts = paginator.page(page)
      except PageNotAnInteger:
          # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
          posts = paginator.page(1)
      except EmptyPage:
          # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
          posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

      css_left = 'col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-centered'
      # css_right = 'col-xs-12 col-lg-3'
      template = 'blog/post/list.html'
      title = 'home'
      page_num = paginator.num_pages
      local = os.getenv('_system_name')
      context = {
          'page': page,
          'posts': posts,
          'tag': tag,
          'title': title,
          'articles': articles,
          'css_left': css_left,
          'paginator': paginator,
          'page_num': page_num,
          'local': local,
          'query': query
          # 'css_right': css_right
          # 'latest': latest_article
      }
      return render(request, template, context)


  def post_detail(request, slug=None):
      post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

      # List of similar posts
      post_tags_ids = post.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
      similar_posts = Post.published.filter(tags__in=post_tags_ids)\
          .exclude(id=post.id)
      similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags'))\
          .order_by('-same_tags', '-publish')[:4]

      css_left = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-8'
      css_right = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 pull-right'
      title = 'detail'
      template = 'blog/post/detail.html'
      context = {
          "post": post,
          'css_left': css_left,
          'css_right': css_right,
          'title': title,
          'similar_posts': similar_posts
      }
      return render(request, template, context)


  def post_create(request):
      if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
          raise Http404
      form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
      if form.is_valid():
          instance = form.save(commit=True) # changed from form.save(commit=False)
          instance.save()
          messages.success(request, "Created !!")
          return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
      template = "blog/post/post_form.html"
      context = {
          "form": form
      }
      return render(request, template, context)


  def post_update(request, slug=None):
      if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
          raise Http404
      instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
      form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
      if form.is_valid():
          instance = form.save(commit=True)
          instance.user = request.user
          instance.save()
          messages.success(request, "Saved !!")
          return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
      template = "blog/post/post_form.html"
      context = {
          "instance": instance,
          "name": instance.title,
          "form": form,
      }
      return render(request, template, context)


  def post_delete(request, id):
      if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
          raise Http404
      instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
      instance.delete()
      messages.success(request, "Deleted !!")
      return redirect('blog:post_list')
```

If my code seems a bit verbose or untidy It's because I learned from various sources. Any guidance on this will be apreciated

Comment: post your  `views` code

Comment: @itzmeontv Thanks for responding I edited the post above

Comment: You really have a lot to look through here. It's not easy to get an idea what exactly is going wrong. Could you pin point which sections of the code you believe to malfunction?

Comment: @nO_OnE_910 I think the issue may be in my formys.py. i think it has something to do with the widget. I deleted most text that I thought was irrelevant. Someone asked me to post my views.py. Ive reduced it check it out now.

Comment: `default=timezone.now` hints at the fact, that this field is not filled during creation. Can you try different default values and see if then the new default value is applied to the Posts?